# AutoCompleteEditor(react-data-grid) not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-data-grid

Actually,im working in reactjs.Imported the npm react-data-grid,in that im using a AutoCompleteEditor in a column to select the listed values. It was working fine before and now working in firefox etc.. Now,im not sure may be the chrome is updated the AutoCompleteEditor list is not showing in the react-data-grid table. Do know why its not showing?
Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using chrome/safari and AutoCompleteEditor works fine.

Setup options

```
const commonDuration = [
  { id: 0, title: '0:15' }, { id: 1, title: '0:30' }, { id: 2, title: '0:45' },
  { id: 3, title: '1:00' }, { id: 4, title: '1:30' }, { id: 5, title: '2:00' }
];
```

in columns

```
editor: <AutoCompleteEditor options={commonDuration} />
```